# How to set CSS styles within Link function of Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I'm attempting to set CSS styles on a certain class within a custom Angular directive when it is clicked. I want to accomplish this (and any other DOM manipulation) within the Link function.
Below is what I have so far, but I'm getting an `address.on is not a function` error. How would I properly set the CSS `-webkit-filter: none` on the `blur` class when `blur` class elements are clicked?

```
function link(scope, element, attributes) {
  var address = element[0].getElementsByClassName('blur');
  address.on('click', function() {
    address.css({'-webkit-filter': 'none'});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`address` is a DOM element. You need to wrap it in `angular.element` to turn it into a jqLite object:

```
function link(scope, element, attributes) {
  var address = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('blur'));
  address.on('click', function() {
    address.css({'-webkit-filter': 'none'});
  });
}
```